# How to create multiple MQQueueConnectionFactory for multiple Queue Manager

Tags: spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, message-queue, spring-jms

I am trying to configure one @JMSListener which will listen to multiple queue managers in my Springboot application which is listening to IBM MQ. Below are the 2 bean i have created and the requirement is to listen to both queue actively :

```
@Value("${ibm.mq.queueManager.A}")
String jmsMQConnectionFactoryA;

@Value("${ibm.mq.queueManager.B}")
String jmsMQConnectionFactoryB;

@Bean
@Primary
public MQQueueConnectionFactory jmsMQConnectionFactoryB() {
    MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    URL url = JMSConfiguration.getURL(this.urlFileLocation);
    try {
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setClientReconnectOptions(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_Q_MGR);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setCCDTURL(url);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(jmsMQConnectionFactoryB);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mqQueueConnectionFactory;
}

   

    @Bean
    public MQQueueConnectionFactory jmsMQConnectionFactoryB() {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        URL url = JMSConfiguration.getURL(this.urlFileLocation);
        try {
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setClientReconnectOptions(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_Q_MGR);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setCCDTURL(url);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(jmsMQConnectionFactoryA);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mqQueueConnectionFactory;
    }
```

EDIT 1 :

Added 2 containerFactory using above connections and 2 JMSTemplate (as i need to publish message as well) Below is the updated working code

```
@Bean
    JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsContainerFactoryA() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new 
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(jmsMQConnectionFactoryA());
        factory.setRecoveryInterval((long) 60000);
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(2);
        factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        // factory.setMaxMessagesPerTask(concurrencyLimit);
        return factory;
    }

@Bean
JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsContainerFactoryB() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(jmsMQConnectionFactoryB());
    factory.setRecoveryInterval((long) 60000);
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(2);
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    // factory.setMaxMessagesPerTask(concurrencyLimit);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public MQQueue jmsResponseQueue() {
    MQQueue queue = null;
    try {
        queue = new MQQueue("QueueOut");
        queue.setBaseQueueName(wmq_out_base_queue);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return queue;
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplateB() {
    JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jmsMQConnectionFactoryB());
    template.setDefaultDestination(jmsResponseQueue());
    template.setMessageConverter(oxmMessageConverter());
    return template;
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplateA() {
    JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jmsMQConnectionFactoryA());
    template.setDefaultDestination(jmsResponseQueue());
    template.setMessageConverter(oxmMessageConverter());
    return template;
}
```

Class2.java

```
 @Value("${wmq_out_base_queue}")
    String wmq_out_base_queue;

    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplateA;
    
    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplateB;

   @JmsListener(containerFactory="jmsContainerFactoryA",destination = "${wmq_in_base_queue}")
    public void reciveMessageA(Message message) {
      LOGGER.info("Received message is: " + message); 
      this.jmsTemplateA.convertAndSend(wmq_out_base_queue, "Some Message");
   }
 
  @JmsListener(containerFactory="jmsContainerFactoryB",destination = "${wmq_in_base_queue}")
    public void reciveMessageB(Message message) {
      LOGGER.info("Received message is: " + message); 
      this.jmsTemplateA.convertAndSend(wmq_out_base_queue, "Some Message2");
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable JMS auto configuration and configure 2 connection factories, 2 container factories using those connection factories and 2 JmsTemplates (if you are also publishing).

> I am trying to configure one @JMSListener which will listen to multiple queue managers

In order to have a `@JmsListener` to do this you need to add 2 `@JmsListener` annotations to the method, with each one having the `containerFactory` property set to the respective container factory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is working now. One more suggestion i would need. The requirement is to create 2 more connection for 2 more queue manager only in production. So in production env i will have 2 more queue manager  jmsMQConnectionFactoryC & jmsMQConnectionFactoryD along with existing and for all lower environments it will have only jmsMQConnectionFactoryA & jmsMQConnectionFactoryA.  What would be the optimal way to design this,

Comment: Put C & D in a `@Profile` so they are only registered in production - see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-definition-profiles-java

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Now with the help of spring.profiles.active & Profile i am able to control the Bean registration. But how do i control the  JmsListener method? as for non prod envs C & D beans are not registered and i have mentioned them in @JmsListener(containerFactory="jmsContainerFactoryC" will throw bean not found error

Comment: Instead of omitting the beans in the profile, for the container factories; set the `autoStartup` to false (use a `@Value` and property set to true or false). Or put those `@JmsListener`s in a bean that is also in the production profile (and call the other JmsListener method).